# How to find equations of tangent lines to the graph passing through a line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to find equations of tangent lines to the graph $f(x)=x/(x-1)$ passing through point $(-1,5)$?

#### Progress

I used the quotient rule and got $f'(x)=-1/(x-1)^2$, but I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: What have you tried to do? Why didn't it work? Do you have any idea how to start?

Comment: i used the quotient rule and got f'(x)=-1/(x-1)^2, but i have no idea how to continue

Comment: Do you know what the derivative tells you about the tangent line?

Comment: Use basic calculus?

Comment: slope of the tangent line?

Comment: Good, the slope of the tangent. What next?

Answer (score 2):

Remember your analytic geometry class(or your calculus class, but analytic geometry is clearer if you're not so accomodated to calculus) and it's formula; $$y-y_0=\lambda (x-x_0)$$

The point is $(-1,5)$ ,those are your $(x_0,y_0)$ respectively. Now remember what the first derivative of a functions really means(keyword; slope). That's your $\lambda$. Reconstructing the above formula you now have $$C: y-y_0=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

Your point $(-1,5) \in C \iff 5-y_0=f'(x_0)(-1-x_0)$ but $(x_0,y_0) \in f \iff 5-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(-1-x_0)$

You now just have to solve for $x_0$ find $y_0$ from that and plug them into the equation that gives the tangent.